# Frameworks and Libraries missing on the SVN checkout, XCode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I checkout a version from SVN, but when i run the project it shows Linker errors and missing frameworks. I solved the problem by adding again the frameworks and missing '.a' files from the folder to Build Phases-> Link Binary with Libraries and also I cleared the Library search path and Framework search paths to make the project run.

But when I checkout from SVN each time I encounter these same errors, how to set the relative path for the Libraries and frameworks. Every member of the project is encountering the same error when they checkout on their Mac machine. How to resolve this error.

Any help is appreciated.

In the below screen the search path shows only the local path, how to change it to absolute path so that every time it can fetch from XCode itself.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on '**Framework Search Paths**' and make changes as shown in below image.

[image]

Comment: thanks, frameworks has been added but i have some files like libUAirship-3.0.2.a and libPayPalMobile.a is missing.

Comment: Search those file in your checkout folder. If not found it may not added in svn.

Comment: thanks, while inlcudeing the '.a' files in addition to $(SRCROOT) we have to inlude the local path also. Yhanks its comming now.